# cleveref counter and ref label number format with padding zeroes

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using `cleverref` and a custom counter to typeset a special kind of reference,
where I need the same text on the definition side and the reference side.

Currently I use `\textbf{F\arabic{thefeatures}}` on the definition side and
`\crefformat{thefeatures}{#2\textbf{F#1}#3}` to format the references.

However instead of the `F<number>` I'd like to switch to `F<number padded by zeroes>`.

While I can use the `fmtcount` package for the definition side
(and use the `\padzeroes` command with decimal output),
this doesnt work for the reference labels.

Current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{thefeatures}
\setcounter{thefeatures}{0}

\crefname{thefeatures}{feature}{features}

\newcommand{\deffeat}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{thefeatures}
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{F\arabic{thefeatures}}
}

\crefformat{thefeatures}{#2\textbf{F#1}#3}


\begin{document}

\deffeat{test} feature test


\deffeat{test2} feature test2


\Cref{test} test ref

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem using the xstrings package
and thanks to [controling padding using the xstring package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80212/controling-padding-using-the-xstring-package)

the code for the pad command i use is

```
\newcommand\padfrom[1]{%
\StrLen{#1}[\templen]%
\StrGobbleRight{000}{\templen}%
#1}
```

Answer (score 6):

Manual approach:

```
\textbf{%
  F%
  \ifnum\value{thefeatures}<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{thefeatures}<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{thefeatures}<10 0\fi
  \arabic{thefeatures}%
}%
```

---

A possible implementation that works for you is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{thefeatures}
\setcounter{thefeatures}{0}

\crefname{thefeatures}{feature}{features}

\newcommand{\deffeat}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{thefeatures}%
  \label{#1}%
  \printfeat{\arabic{thefeatures}}%
}

\crefformat{thefeatures}{#2\protect\printfeat{#1}#3}

\newcommand{\printfeat}[1]{%
  \textbf{%
    F%
    \ifnum\value{thefeatures}<1000 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{thefeatures}<100 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{thefeatures}<10 0\fi
    #1%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\deffeat{test} feature test


\deffeat{test2} feature test2


\Cref{test} test ref

\end{document}
```

Watch out for spurious spaces in your definitions.

Comment: and how would i use that within crefformat ?

where the counter value is somewhat different

the only place where this would work, is where the fmtcount package would aready work

Comment: it seems you completely missed that the counter value is always the last one, no the one of the referenced item

Comment: @Ronny: Did you compile at least twice? This should not be the case.

Comment: the script i test with is compiled 4 times (due to bibtex)

Comment: to be clar, i added a printing for the value of the counter using \arabic{thefeatures} in the format (so it fits his code) - and as expected the counter was on the last value, since it doesnt get a new value in the format

so the noly way to get the counter in the crefformat seems to be the one that comes in as string